# Pyspark: How to extract readable feature importance from spark-ml Random Forest

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

From this question [pyspark-mllib-random-forest-feature-importances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971989/pyspark-mllib-random-forest-feature-importances) I see there is a method called `featureImportances` that return a SparseVector.

The output is something like this:

```
SparseVector(2, {0: 0.6, 1:0.4})
```

My question is how can I associate the name of the columns with the original name of the function?
Is there a way to extract the columns names from the RandomForestClassifier object?

EDIT:
The model is the second stage of a pipeline. The first stage is a VectorAssembler object used to define the input columns for the model.

Comment: random forest takes on input two columns, label and features column of type Vector, so what you mean about "column names" ?

Comment: That's exactly the problem, I lose the feature names in the previous step of the pipeline when I use the VectorAssembler object. I'll edit the question